# WEMOS D1 12V power source

Tags: power-supply, display

[image][image]In my project I am using WeMos D1 R1 to which I have connected I2C display 1602A , infrared LED (for remote control) and DHT11.
As display and sensors are working on 5V I am using voltage level shifter.

Everything is working fine so I have completed my project and decide to power it with 12V power jack. But without success. When I power it with USB power source it works fine. But when I connect it to 12V source display does not work. The boards itself seems working fine as it is connecting to my cloud and sending data.

Does anybody have idea why I have such strange behavior ..? Thanks

Comment: An error in your component selection, design or build is causing this.

Comment: We can't possibly know what kind of 12V supply you have and how 12V is converted to 5V for the project, and how have you connected the modules together. Please add this info.

Comment: i have added picture of the board. it is not easy to make photo of my project as there are to many wires :). I am not converting the power input it is done by board. In case i am using USB it works , in case DC power jack ( 1000mA power supply ) not. From board i am using D14/D15 for display , 3.3 V output connect to one side of voltage level shifter ( same for 5V side )...D14/D15 are connect to 3.3 V side and 5V side is connected to display.

Comment: Have a look at the schema for the board and then start measuring where the voltage is disappearing, normal troubleshooting. And I would guess that the AMS1117, power regulator is bad.

Comment: Thanks Mats.. So simple :) . I have measured the output and in case DC power jack is used , 5V output from board gives only 3.5V . So mystery solved. Thanks